# Multiprocessing debug techniques

Tags: python, debugging, deadlock, multiprocessing

I'm having trouble debugging a multi-process application (specifically using a process pool in python's multiprocessing module). I have an apparent deadlock and I do not know what is causing it. The stack trace is not sufficient to describe the issue, as it only displays code in the multiprocessing module.

Are there any python tools, or otherwise general techniques used to debug deadlocks?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yah, debugging deadlocks is fun.  You can set the logging level to be higher -- see [the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) for a description of it, but really quickly:

```
import multiprocessing, logging
logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
logger.setLevel(multiprocessing.SUBDEBUG)
```

Also, add logging for anything in your code that deals with a resource or whatnot that might be in contention.  Finally, shot in the dark:  spawning off child processes during an import might cause a problem.

Comment: Yep - lots of logging, poor as it may be, is still the best overall approach to isolating and eventually locating and fixing deadlock issues... whence the +1. multiprocessing has specific deadlock issues with its Queue, that are well documented -- check you aren't running into those, maybe.

Answer (score 12):

In order to *avoid* deadlocks in the first place, learning good practices is useful, as parallel processing is indeed quite subtle.  The (free) [Little Book of Semaphores](http://www.greenteapress.com/semaphores/) can be a very enjoyable read!