# multiprocessing.Pool() hanging in qsub with Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am running into an issue with `Numpy` and `Multiprocessing` in a `qsub` environment.

Specifically, I have this Python code:

```
#full_comparisons.py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

output = np.ndarray(
        shape=(x, y, z, a),
        dtype=[('site', '>i4'), ('html', '>f4'), ('js', '>f4'), ('png', '>f4')])
##NOTE: output size is only .002 GB, so RAM shouldn't be an issue.
print("Before pool")
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
print("After pool")
```

And I have run `qsub` as follows (i.e. I have tried each of these), where `./comparisons` just calls `python3 full_comparisons.py`:

```
qsub -V comparisons # -V keep environment variables
qsub -l vlong -V comparisons #-l vlong lets it run infinitely
qsub -V -pe smp 32 comparisons #parallelizes with more processors
qsub -l vlong -V -pe smp 32
qsub -V -pe smp 16 comparisons
qsub -V -pe smp 8 comparisons
```

Among others.

In every case, I am having `Before pool` print, and then it just hangs.

The reason I believe this is related to the cluster is because running `./comparisons` works fine locally, with the multiprocessing. The only problem arises from using `qsub`. Perhaps there is a bug that affects using `Numpy` and `Multiprocessing` that I do not know about.

ALL RELATED CODE:

```
import subprocess
import os
import csv
import itertools
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import jaccard
import file_names

def compare_lambda(x, y, dict_1, dict_2):
    ...

def compare_all():
    pairs = itertools.combinations(range(GLOBAL_VAR1), 2)
    ids_to_sites, sites_to_ids = init_sites()
    output = np.ndarray(
        shape=(GLOBAL_VAR1, GLOBAL_VAR1, GLOBAL_VAR2, GLOBAL_VAR3),
        dtype=[('x', '>i4'), ('y', '>f4'), ('z', '>f4'), ('a', '>f4')])
    print("Before pool")
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    print("After pool")
    compared_vals = pool.starmap(compare_lambda, list(map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], dict_1, dict_2), pairs)))

    for (a, b, compared) in compared_vals:
        ...
print(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) #works fine
compare_all()
```

EDIT: At the recommendation of @sehafoc I enabled logging for multiprocessing. Interestingly when I ran the multiprocessing on the computing cluster I had this:

```
Before pool
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 47690244722688
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 47690244726784
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 47690244730880
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 47690244734976
[DEBUG/MainProcess] added worker
[DEBUG/MainProcess] added worker
[DEBUG/MainProcess] added worker
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] added worker
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] child process calling self.run()
```

Whereas when I ran it locally I had this output:

```
Before pool
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140313792987136
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140313792983040
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140313792978944
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 140313792974848
[DEBUG/MainProcess] added worker
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] added worker
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] added worker
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] child process calling self.run()
[DEBUG/MainProcess] added worker
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] child process calling self.run()
After pool
```

Comment: Pool.__init__() looks like it does a bit of work.  I'm not familiar with qsub but I do suspect your problem is there.  I recommend turning on debugging to see if it gets you any closer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1353037/3776268

Comment: Hmm. See edit to question above with details of this @sehafoc

Answer (score 0):

Update: Forced a `sys.out.flush` to get it to print. Seems that `qsub` flushes very infrequently.